# PHP using Guzzle to pass through PDF not working while displaying in browser

Tags: php, pdf, guzzle, rest-client

(FIXED: See comment below.)

I have a website that runs PHP that accesses a REST-service running .NET Core. The REST-API returns a PDF behind OAuth2 security.

Now I want the PHP page to pass through the PDF that is in memory.

I am doing sth. like this:

```
$getPdfUrl = "https://<my url>";
$response = $guzzleClient->request("GET", $getPdfUrl, array("headers" => array("Authorization" => "Bearer <access token>")));

$lengthArray = $response->getHeader('Content-Length');
$length = $lengthArray[0];

header('Content-Type: application/pdf; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Length: '.$length);
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename='details.pdf'");

echo $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

This works perfectly fine, if I use Content-Dispositon as attachment. The PDF is okay.

However, I see binary crap like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQYQ4.png when I do it inline. My goal is display the PDF directly by the browser.

I guess it is a little error, but I don't see it.

Update: Thanks to the comments below. Both were correct. I contradict to my own (deleted) comment and agree. Due to some magic of a used CMS the text/html header was already sent and caused that error.

The code above is correct.

Comment: Check your browser's web inspector and ensure the response headers match what you're setting. Possibly you've already output something and the headers you're setting are being ignored.

Comment: I agree with @miken32 - this is most likely happening because you have a Content-type: text/html in here.  Keep in mind if you're using some framework, they tend to capture the output in a buffer and send it - as if it's a view.